# Import iTunes Playlist to Spotify

Tags: itunes, playlists, spotify

I decided to get back into Spotify knowing how versatile the app is. The problem I am having is that there is no simple way to import iTunes playlists in the newest version `1.0.10.107.gd0dfca3a` anymore.

Is there another alternative to importing these playlists into Spotify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tunify. Install it on your device and the rest is magic ;)
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunify/id1008534301?l=es&mt=8

Comment: The app is now named `Send2FY` and it works really well. Best of all, it's free.